# Как сделать переход от одного ViewController к другому по условию? [xCode, SWIFT]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Я хочу сделать экран авторизации в VK, чтобы при открытии приложения, открывался первый экран, где идет проверка условия, и если условие выполняется, то открывается второй экран. Грубо говоря, если сессия сохранилась, то сразу открывается следующий экран.

Как реализовать переход по нажатию на клавишу - знаю, а как это можно реализовать без лишних манипуляций от пользователя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать проверку в методе `ViewDidLoad`. Если она проходит сразу делайте push в следующий контроллер.

А вообще лучше проверку вынести за уровень контроллера.
Создать SleepController(который из себя представляет просто imageView с вашим лого из `LaunchScreen`)
Далее сделайте проверку в каком нибудь классе на наличие авторизации. Если авторизация успешна, переходите сразу в Первый экран, если нет, то переходите на окно авторизации.

Answer (score 0):

В didFinishLaunchingWithOptions делай проверку и пуш нужный контроллер. Но лучше чтобы это вынести на уровень класса чтобы другой обьект решал какой контроллер пушить.